# Big Shaq real name?

Tags: names

What is the real name of Big Shaq who made Mans Not Hot?

I was wondering since his name probably isn't the exact same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

His real name is Michael Dapaah. Big Shaq is a character he invented. He is not actually a rapper, but he's a comedian.